# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: vue.js, axios, apigee

I have a Vue.js application that uses axios to send request to ApiGee Server.

This is the code i use to send request to APIgee.

```
    const headers = {
      'X-API-Key': 'randomKey123123'
    }

    return axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: url,
      headers: headers
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response)
    })
```

from the ApiGee, I can see OPTIONS request being received first since I done the request from the client side browser.
I can also see the `X-API-Key` header key but the value is missing.

The error I'm getting from the browser console is

```
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code helped me you can try this format:

```
created() {
  // POST request using axios with set headers
  const article = { title: "Vue POST Request Example" };
  const headers = { 
     'X-API-Key': 'randomKey123123'
  };
  axios.post(url, article, { headers })
    .then(response => console.log(response.data)
   );
}
```

Comment: I tried that but using get request. the header's value not being passed only the `X-API-Key`